# Cómo acceder y extraer Datos de una API por medio de JS y JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Hola **estoy en proceso de aprendizaje**, así que ser un poco blando conmigo, la cuestión es: Quiero hacer que la consola me de:
`//Hola, yo soy Luke Skywalker y soy del planeta Tatooine` y en cambio me da el mensaje `//Hola, yo soy Luke Skywalker y soy del planeta http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/`(Dirección de la información) o `//Hola, yo soy Luke Skywalker y soy del planeta undefined` , no he logrado hacer que suceda la primero por ningún medio que sea de mi entender, estoy utilizando la API de Star Wars ( https://swapi.dev/ ).

Básicamente, a través de los Personajes (https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/) lo que quiero es acceder y extraer la información de "HOMEWORD" : http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/ (planetas). y que se muestre
`//Hola, yo soy Luke Skywalker y soy del planeta **Tatooine** que tiene un periodo orbital de **304** dias` , por ejemplo... Gracias por Adelantado :)

-------------------*RECOMIENDO VER LAS IMAGENES*------------

Dejo este código por aquí....

```
const API_URL='https://swapi.dev/api/';
const PEOPLE_URL= 'people/:id';
const HOMEWORD_URL= 'planets/:id';

const options={crossDomain: true};

const onPeopleResponse= function (personaje) {
    // console.log(arguments)
    console.log(`Hola, yo soy ${personaje.name} y soy del planeta ${personaje.homeworld}`) //(Se que asi no se hace)
 }

function obtenerPersonaje(id) {
    const url=`${API_URL}${PEOPLE_URL.replace( `:id`, id )}`;
    $.get(url, options, onPeopleResponse)
}

let obtenerCienPersonajes =78;
for (let i = 1; i < obtenerCienPersonajes; i++) {
    obtenerPersonaje(i)
}
//Esto me da la consola con este codigo:

//Hola, yo soy Luke Skywalker y soy del planeta http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/

//Hola, yo soy Ratts Tyerel y soy del planeta http://swapi.dev/api/planets/38/

//Quiero que me de:

//Hola, yo soy Luke Skywalker y soy del planeta Tatooine
```

Imágenes por aquí

Persona

[image: Información del Personaje 1 de la API]

Planeta

[image: Información del Planeta 1 en la API]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiero que se revisen los conceptos de **Event Driven Programming/Asynchronous programming**, **JS no es asincrónico**, es [**sincrónico**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035645/when-is-javascript-synchronous).

Aquí una solución simple basada en el patrón [**Continuation Passing Style**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), respetando lo más posible el código original.

1. Primero se va por personaje endpoint
2. Luego, se va por planeta endpoint
3. Finalmente, se ejecuta la función de continuación `onPeopleResponse`

El código original va bien, solo falta ir por los datos de la **API/endpoint planetas**, hay diferentes datos en cada endpoint, usamos el método asynchronous JS [get](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) de jquery y funciones de continuación (callback):

```
    //CPS with callback
     $.get(url_people, options, function (data, status){
         //console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
         characterName = data.name
         //console.log(characterName);
         //CPS with callback nested
         $.get(url_planet, options, function (data, status){
             //console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
             planetName = data.name;
             //console.log(planetName);
             //ultima funcion de continuacion
             onPeopleResponse(characterName, planetName);
         });
    });
```

CPS es muy usado, tiene sus desventajas en cuestión de cómo se estructura una pieza de código asincrónico, el bien conocido **callback hell** (muchas funciones de continuación anidadas).

Luego de comprender este patrón CPS, lo mejor es estudiar **Promises y async/await**, que son otros patrones más actuales, que permiten estructurar el código asincrónico de una forma mas sincrónica (sin callback hell).

```js
const API_URL='https://swapi.dev/api/';
      const PEOPLE_URL= 'people/:id';
      const HOMEWORD_URL= 'planets/:id';

      const options={crossDomain: true};

      const onPeopleResponse= function (personaje, planeta) {
        
          console.log(`Hola, yo soy ${personaje} y soy del planeta ${planeta}`) //(Se que asi no se hace)
      }

      function obtenerPersonaje(id) {
          const options={crossDomain: true};
          const url_people=`${API_URL}${PEOPLE_URL.replace( `:id`, id )}`;
          const url_planet=`${API_URL}${HOMEWORD_URL.replace( `:id`, id )}`;
          let characterName = "";
          let planetName = "";
          //CPS with callback
           $.get(url_people, options, function (data, status){
            //console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            characterName = data.name
            //console.log(characterName);
            //CPS with callback nested
            $.get(url_planet, options, function (data, status){
              //console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
              planetName = data.name;
              //console.log(planetName);
              //funcion de continuacion
              onPeopleResponse(characterName, planetName);
            }).fail(function(e){
              if(e.status == 404){
                console.log("No se encontro el recurso:" + e.status);
              }
            });
          }).fail(function(e){
              if(e.status == 404){
                console.log("No se encontro el recurso:" + e.status);
              }
          });
      }

      let obtenerCienPersonajes =78;
      for (let i = 1; i < obtenerCienPersonajes; i++) {
          obtenerPersonaje(i)
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Nota: falta evaluar el **status**, hay peticiones en la API Star Wars que regresan el estatus 404. Otro tema a estudiar y tomar en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

primero hablemos de tus errores en el código, entiendo que recién estés aprendiendo,

> primero: Los `string` dentro de constantes no es buena practica.

> segundo: Tienes mucho código de mas, te lo resumiré en una sola función.

> tercero: en la consola se muestra `//Hola, yo soy Luke Skywalker y soy del planeta http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/` por que estas pintando simplemente la url de todos los datos de los planetas, deberías hacer una petición a esa url y así obtener el nombre del planeta.

```js
const options={crossDomain: true};

const buscarPersonaje = async id => {
   try{
    const { name } =  await $.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${id}`, options)
    const response = await $.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/planets/${id}`, options)
    console.log(`Hola yo soy ${name} y vengo del platena ${response.name}`)
    
   }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
   }
}

buscarPersonaje(1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

te explico lo que hice, cree una función asíncrona para poder obtener los datos, es por eso que agrege las palabras claves `async/await`, por defecto javascript ejecuta código asíncrono, lo que pasa aca es que estamos haciendo una petición y esto puede tardar, pero javascript dice: ok esto es tema del backend y no mío, y sigue ejecutando código, entonces con las palabras claves `async` le decimo que vamos a estar trabajando asíncronamente, con la palabra clave `await` le decimos que dicha función va a tomar algo de tiempo, entonces en esa linea de código javascript va a esperar a que termine, una vez termine voy a guardar la respuesta de la api en una variable, como puedes ver estoy `desestructurando` la respuesta y solamente estoy obteniendo el nombre del personaje, luego como `name` ya esta declarada entonces guarda la respuesta completa sin `desestructurar`, luego imprimo por consola el resultado, como eres nuevo en javascript tal vez te preguntaras, que es ese `try` y ese `catch`, y ese `error` de donde sale? ok, esto se usa comúnmente para ejecutar código asíncrono, lo que hago es ejecutar código asíncrono dentro del `try`, si por alguna razón hay un error en la petición a la api, el `catch` lo capturara, es por eso que lo muestro por consola, para ver que error sucedió, creo que eso es todo, bienvenido a javascript, es un lenguaje muy bueno y tiene una sintaxis encantadora, suerte en tu recorrido.